# unable to get the complete width of a table

Tags: css

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Column 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row 1</td>
            <td> Row !</td>
            <td> Row 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Unable to get the full width to the table header as well as the body any help

https://jsfiddle.net/c714kt0z/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `colspan ="3"` because you have max 3 column in a `row`.

```css
table{
    width:100%;
}

thead{
    background-color: #eee;
    width:100%;
}

tbody{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th  colspan="3"> Column 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">Header 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Row 1</td>
            <td> Row !</td>
            <td> Row 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```